# Normal map and tangent vector

Tags: matrix

This picture is what I believe how to transform the tangent vector if it and the normal vector are not perpendicular using **Gram Schmidt process**. But I don't think it's true because I always see this:

```
mat3 normalMatrix = transpose(inverse(mat3(model)));
vec3 T = normalize(normalMatrix * aTangent);
vec3 N = normalize(normalMatrix * aNormal);
T = normalize(T - dot(T, N) * N);
vec3 B = cross(N, T);
```

I already read explanations about this topic but I can't understand them. Please correct my errors and make it clearer.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake is: cos(omega) is not equal to |N|/|T|.

Since N and T are unit vectors |N|/|T| = 1/1 = 1 always.

The true definition is just:

cos(omega) = dot(N, T)

dot(N, T) = |Delta N| / |T| = |Delta N| / 1 = |Delta N|

In othet words:

Delta N = N * dot(N, T)

Now the Gram Schmidt is:

T' = T - N * dot(N, T)

Comment: Thank you for your help but please clear me about the part: Delta N = N * dot( N, T) because previously |Delta N| = dot (N, T). I'm quite confused!

Comment: By definition: Delta N / |Delta N| = N, then Delta N = N * |Delta N|  , then the rest follows.